# Spring Boot 2, HSQL, and unit tests with multiple schemas. Unknown schemas with autogeneration on

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I have an application running Spring Boot 2.0.6 in which requires data across two schemas of an Oracle database. The application runs fine when defined however the unit tests using HSQL do not seem to handle auto schema generation.

I've created a sample project to demonstrate the issue. This is likely a configuration issue however I've yet to figure it out. I've worked around this in the past by simply using data.sql and manually creating all of the ddl with SQL however this time it's more complicated and I'm looking to reduce the work.

[Example Repository](https://github.com/rlperez/multi-schema-unittest-example)